# How to compute Inverse Stationary Wavelet Transform of an Image?

Tags: image-processing, signal-processing, wavelet, haar-wavelet

I understand the forward Stationary Wavelet Transform and how it is implemented on the diagonal, vertical and horizontal components. In fact, I have it implemented. What I don't understand is what exactly is the algorithm to compute Inverse Stationary Wavelet Transform of an image given Vertical, Diagonal and Horizontal components? I have been unable to locate a simple explanation of the algorithm and I will be grateful if someone can assist.

Comment: Have you read this?
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_wavelet_transform

Answer (score -1):

inverse stationary wavelet transform can be used to reconstruct the image with horizontal, vertical and diagonal components. Matlab already has an inbuilt function iswt2() which performs the inverse stationary wavelet transform.

Here is the link which has all the details of the algorithm and it also an example code

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/iswt2.html

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.